# How to undo Eclipse's 'Convert to plug-in project'?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I accidentally converted my Java project into a plug-in one. How would I revert it?
I converted it be right clicking on the project, going to configure and clicking convert to plugin project.
I searched the project settings and the configuration menu, but there seems to be no option to revert it to a normal Java project.
Now, I get a warning stating that the manifest file is not present. This is because I deleted the manifest file generated when I converted the project.
How would I revert this project?

Comment: Create a new Java project.  Carefully, copy each source file from your corrupted Java project to the new Java project.  Delete the corrupted Java project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the Properties for the Project.

Go to the "Project Natures" tab.

Select the "Plug-in Development" nature in the list. Click "Remove" and then "Apply and Close" to remove it. You will get a prompt telling you that this is an advanced operation - choose OK.

You may need to clean up any "build.properties" that gets left